# Limit AllowUsers to specific IPs from Github actions

Tags: linux, github, deployment, github-actions, sshd

As a security measure, I have on my server:

```
AllowUsers username@myip
```

On

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

So only me, or someone with my ip, can login.

Now I need to use an action on github to start making an automated deploy (rsync).

I can just comment that line and it works fine, but I believe a good practice would be to set something like this:

```
AllowUsers username@myip username@githubip
```

Since they probably have a ton of ips, I don't know exactly what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub publishes the IP addresses it uses for various systems [in its API](https://api.github.com/meta).  You can therefore download the entries for Actions and use them if you like.

However, I should point out that this list is subject to change at any time, and it also contains over 2100 entries, so adding all of those in your config file may not be the best choice, since it might impact performance.  If you do decide to do this, scripting it would be prudent.

My recommendation would be to adopt a different approach for login that isn't IP based.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about "different approach for login that isn't IP based."?

Comment: My suggestion would be that you don't implement IP-based access control if you need access from GitHub Actions.  You can just use only public key-based authentication, in which case, provided the keys are secured, there's no way to break in.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you should be able to use

```
AllowUsers username@myip username@github.com
```

which will, of course, introduce a DNS lookup penalty. But that may be preferable to adding a plethora of IP addresses.  Alternatively you could maken entries for each IP in `/etc/hosts` as you go when you encounter problems.

Comment: This is probably not going to work since the GitHub Actions machines don't have the IP for `github.com`.

Comment: @bk2204 - do they have **A** common domain name?

Comment: I don't know, but I don't believe so.  I believe there are different cloud providers involved, so I think it's unlikely that they do.  In any event, it would not be guaranteed, so I wouldn't implement an access control based on it.

Comment: Oh ... wow. That's suboptimal ;)

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: You tried both suggestions?